# ASP.NET WebForms: Adding controls dynamically to a TableCell of a GridView and recovering them on the PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a `GridView` bound to a `DataSource`. The last column of it has a literal control with a comma-separated string of numbers. That string must be splitted and those numbers must be in their own `TextBox` (I don't know how many of them are in advance):

[image: GridView]

Here is the last column definition:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cantidades">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal ID="litCantidades" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CANTIDADES") %>'></asp:Literal>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

After, in the `RowDataBound` event, I do something like this:

```
private void CreaControlesCeldaCantidades(GridViewRow gridRow)
{
    //Array of numbers got from the bound literal control in the cell.
    int[] cantidades = GetCantidadesFromRow(gridRow);
    TableCell cantidadesCell = gridRow.Cells[9];

    //I don't want the literal control anymore.
    cantidadesCell.Controls.Clear();
    int i = 0;

    //I create one TextBox per each number to put it
    //inside, so the user can edit it.
    foreach (var cantidad in cantidades)
    {
        var cantidadTextBox = new TextBox();
        cantidadTextBox.ID = "txtCantidad" + i++;
        cantidadTextBox.Text = cantidad.ToString();
        cantidadTextBox.Width = Unit.Pixel(10);
        cantidadTextBox.CssClass = "txtCantidad";
        cantidadesCell.Controls.Add(cantidadTextBox);
    }
}
```

So far, so good. The problem comes on the `PostBack`. I try to recover the numbers edited by the user, but when I try to do it, all those `TextBox` created are gone:

```
private void ValidarEntradasNumericas()
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in grvMaterialesTareas.Rows)
    {
        var chkSistematico = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSistematico");
        var txtSustitucion = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtSustitucion");
        var sustitucion = 0;

        if (chkSistematico.Checked)
        {
            txtSustitucion.Text = "100";
        }
        else if (!int.TryParse(txtSustitucion.Text, out sustitucion))
        {
            throw new Exception("Uno de los códigos de sustitución indicados no es numérico. Por favor, corrija su valor.");
        }

        var cantidad = 0;
        var cantidadesCell = row.Cells[9];

        //Fails miserably and I don't know why :'(
        foreach (TextBox txtCantidad in cantidadesCell.Controls)
        {
            if (!int.TryParse(txtCantidad.Text, out cantidad))
            {
                throw new Exception("Una de las cantidades indicadas no es numérica. Por favor, corrija su valor.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to know why that solution doesn't work and how I can make it work.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically created Controls must be recreated on every Page Load, and that includes a PostBack. So if you have the Binding of the GridView inside a `IsPostBack` (as you would normally), remove it.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = source;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Second you don't need a Literal in the GridView to get the data in the RowDataBound event

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
    TableCell cantidadesCell = e.Row.Cells[0];

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string[] cantidades = row["CANTIDADES"].ToString().Split(',');

        for (int i = 0; i < cantidades.Length; i++)
        {
            var cantidadTextBox = new TextBox();
            cantidadTextBox.ID = "txtCantidad" + i;
            cantidadTextBox.Text = cantidades[i];
            cantidadTextBox.Width = 50;
            cantidadTextBox.CssClass = "txtCantidad";
            cantidadesCell.Controls.Add(cantidadTextBox);
        }
    }
}
```